# Update a defaultdict when iterating through a tuple during a trick in a poke game

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I wish to get a input of a tuple of 4 tuples, which contains 4 tricks played in a certain stage in the poker game. I was able to get some results from it which would give me the possible winner and locate the index of that card in the tuple.

Here's an example:

```
(('9D', '9S', '3S', '0D'),)
```

> the tuple contains 4 tuples inside however it can still be used as an valid input when in this form.

I was able to compare certain values and get the index of that card.

Example:

```
Due to certain issues this snippet has been deleted, please refer to the answer below
```

You may see that I am using a very basic way just to test out the possible outcome. Right now I'm stuck at the stage where it wants me to record the winner. Or more specifically, record the number of tricks won by the certain winner. Note that the player number is predetermined by the index position in the tuple.

```
('9D',   '9S',   '3S',   '0D')
 Player0 Player1 Player2 Player3
```

My goal is to 1. Record the number of winning tricks of a player. 2. Update a key as that player and increment the value of that key by 1. Then follow the pattern to process all the tuple of cards.

A sample input:

```
score_phase((0, 0, 0, 0), (('9D', '9S', '3S', '0D'),), '2D')
```

> Desired output should become `(10, 10, 10, 1)`, since nobody except player 4 won the trick, however he was bidding on a 0 that is not the same as the number of trick he won in that phase.

Some problems you may want to point out in the code is because I'm currently trying to get a primary output that may give me some insights. Sadly none has enlighten me so far.
Any help on how to handle this will be much appreciated.

**EDIT**: If player0 won a trick, he will get one point(which may be the output later.) If he bidded a 1 in the `bids`, then he made a trick so he gets 1 + 10(10 for making the correct prediction.) I just want to ask if there is a way to make that happen? I can get the index of a number which indicates who played that card. Thus I may use that and compare it against the bidding tuple and update his score. But I think this may not be possible using solely tuple and lists so I wondered if it is possible to update them in a defaultdict. But other ways to accomplish that are also gratefully appreciated!

Comment: I don't know the logic of the game. If you can just tell which data you want to update other data and the condition, maybe I would get it.

Comment: Just for clarification: If player 4 won why `(10, 10, 10, 1)`?  It seems to indicate that player 1-3 got 10 and player 4 got 1.

Comment: @Nightcrawler That's because player1-3 predicted their bid correctly since they did not win in that trick, so 0 matches a 0 in their win record, thus they have 10. However on the other hand, player4 bidded 0 while winning with a record of 1, so 1 does not match 0, thus he only get the points from the number of wins he had, which is 1, hence the output.

Comment: I am starting to understand. If your players are not identified by name but just an index in the list, then lists will suffice. You can make a mapping from index to name if you don't want them to be anonymous. I will play around with what you told me.

Comment: Mapping could work if it is a single trick, as you may see the tricks tuple consists of 4 tuples. And their position will change which gives me cancer... For example, when entering a second trick the winner will start the trick which means if player4 won the previous trick, he will start, then player1, 2 and 3. So I dunno if mapping will work since their index may vary... And that's where it got me hard... Thank you kind sir. In the meantime I will also make some effort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112575/discussion-between-cookie-jar-and-nightcrawler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of things you need to take care of in your app. Here is some inspiration for your `(10, 10, 10, 1)` part of the question. I have taken the liberty of changing your code a bit. It should still be recognizable though.

```
SPECIALS = {"0": 10, "J": 11, "Q": 12, "K": 13, "A": 14}


def getCardValue(inputVal):
    special = inputVal[:-1]
    return SPECIALS.get(special, int(special))


def score_phase(bids, tricks, deck_top):
    # Unwrap tricks
    tricks = tricks[0]

    # Convert to a high score list.
    result = [0 if deck_top[-1] != x[-1] else getCardValue(x)
              for x
              in tricks]
    best = max(result)

    winners = [i for i in range(len(result)) if result[i] == best]
    print('Winner(s) by index: {}'.format(', '.join(str(winner)
                                                    for winner
                                                    in winners)))

    def score(i):
        if bids[i] > 0:
            if result[i] == best:
                return 11
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            if result[i] == best:
                return 1
            else:
                return 10

    return [score(i) for i in range(len(bids))]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(score_phase((0, 0, 0, 0), (('9D', '9S', '3S', '0D'),), '2D'))
```

Hope it helps a bit.